# How to enlarge an image horizontally in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<td>` in a `<table>`, where I have an image in it. When the screen is re-sized using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+mousewheel, the image has to be enlarged horizontally to fit the screen. I should not use 
`background:repeat-x` property and the width should be 15%; if I re-size, it should be enlarged horizontally.

html:

```
<td id="rightBanner">
```

css:

```css
#rightBanner{
    background-image:url('../images/rightbanner.png');
    width:15%;
    height:95px;
    align:right;
}
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Can you share your test site ?

Comment: Better, can you share a fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it this way:

1. setup width on container table,
2. setup "display: block" on the td
3. setup "background-size: 100% 100%" for the image

*Here is the code:*

**CSS:**

```
#container-table{
    width:100%;
}

#rightBanner{
   display:block;
   background-image:url('../images/rightbanner.png');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   width:15%;
   height:95px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="container-table">
    <tr>
        <td id="rightBanner"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2NNa/2/) is a working example.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try

**HTML:**

```
<td id="rightBanner">
```

**CSS:**

```
#rightBanner{
   background-image:url('../images/rightbanner.png') repeat-x;
   width:15%;
   height:95px;
   align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use background-size: cover or 100%:

```
css: #rightBanner{
   background-image:url('../images/rightbanner.png');
   background-size: 100%;
   width:15%;
   height:95px;
   align:right;
}
```

---

```
background-size: [horizontal percentage] [vertical percentage]
```

If you don't include vertical percentage then this will go accordingly with horizontal percentage.

Comment: If i use the background-size: 100%; its repeating i dont it to be repeated, it should be enlarged horizontally

Comment: it wouldn't repeat but enlarge. If you have problem then use background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: if i use both, nothing happening, nethier enlarge nor repeat :(

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to use repeat-x. You can scale the image in html (although not a good solution).

Please share a sample of page for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#rightBanner{
    background-image:url('../images/rightbanner.png');
    width:15%;
    height:auto;
    align:right;
}
```

by using **height:auto**, your image will resize without loosing it's quality.